how to check how many loop-devices in a linux system are possible to use?
how to check how many loop-devices in a linux system are possible to use?
i need this in a script, are not more than X possible, than end the script with some message...

what is maximum loop devices for linux kernel or are you asking about very old kernels or what?

I've reopened as the other question focused on how many you could configure a system to have while this one asks how to tell how many a system has in its current configuration (from what I understand)

Ah, I missed the point of @frostschutz's answer there that the number of loop devices is no longer limited since Linux 3.1. I hadn't realised that. Closing again.
